# Как конвертировать .doc файлы в .pdf на asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net-core, pdf, ms-word

Нужно сделать отображение word файлов на сайте (Изначально была такая задумка), но порывся два-три дня не нашёл ничего нормального. Далее пришла идея конвертировать .doc файлы в .pdf и потом отображать. Но тут тоже проблемы, до сих пор не могу найти нормальные инструменты для этого, буду крайне благодарен за помощь.

### Что мне нужно:

- API или плагин для работы в оффлайне
- Бесплатный (Бесплатные пробные версии тоже не интересуют, не нужно кидать ссылка на сервисы по конвертации, которые дают ПРОБНУЮ ВЕРСИЮ на 1 час/день/месяц/год)
- Без редиректов (Не отдельной программой, сервисом и т.д., НЕ WOPI, без соединения по http протоколу и другим, чисто встроенный инструмент)
- Без лимитов (Я находил сервисы, где есть бесплатный лимит на месяц, такой тоже не предлагать)
- На платформе .Net Core (Различные API для .Net Standart, .Net Framework не подходят, они просто не совместимы. Так же Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word тоже не подходит, поскольку он тоже для .Net Framework и заточен под работу на Windows)
- Библиотеки, которые используют PowerShell или другие консоли

Может что-то забыл перечислить, то пересмотрел я реально очень много вещей, по этому я и обратился сюда (Для гениев, который будут говорить: "а гуглИть пробАвАли?")

Всем за помощь, кто на это потратит своё время!

Comment: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word ... он тоже для .Net Framework" - это не так. А под какую операционную систему? А откуда возник формат "doc", если это не под Windows? А точно "doc", а не "docx"? А ещё Word позволяет сохранять документы сразу в формате "html".

Comment: @rotabor, "А точно "doc", а не "docx"?" - Да, точно! .doc и .docx это два формата word-файлов. "А под какую операционную систему?" - я на .Net Core пишу, как бы там кроссплатформенность. "А ещё Word позволяет сохранять документы сразу в формате html" - это мне ничего не даёт.

Comment: OpenOffice можно вызвать с аргументами командной строки и конвертировать различные форматы в pdf: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/General/150

Comment: @XelaNimed , я в вопросе написал, что PowerShell и подобные [командные строки] не предлагать, так как эти варианты не подходят для решения задачи

Comment: А по каким причинам не подходит? OpenOffice кроссплатформенный. Если-же это Вам не подходит, то бесплатных библиотек Вы скорее всего не найдёте.

Comment: @XelaNimed, я посмотрел и не нашёл там ни API, ни NuGet пакетов для .Net Core

Comment: Извиняюсь... Раньше, как то делал сие на .Net Core 3.1... Может быть это был LibreOffice (постоянно их путаю)? Вот [свежая статья](https://www.libreofficehelp.com/batch-convert-writer-documents-pdf-libreoffice) с примером использования (doc поддерживается). Но в любом случае и OpenOffice, и LibreOffice поддерживают конвертацию файлов с помощью CLI.

Comment: @XelaNimed, к сожалению, мне не подходит, мне нужно всё автоматизировать кодом в .Net Core (А точнее asp.net core 5), а вручную, в консоли я тоже бы не делал, я бы просто в ворде выбрал бы функцию "сохранить как" и всё))

Comment: @XelaNimed, тем более, там ещё написано вот что: "Note: The steps are different for Windows and Linux. Follow accordingly", т.е., если я работаю на .Net Core и мой проект будет запускать на Linux или на MacOS, то ничего не получится (((

Comment: Не вижу проблемы определить текущую операционную систему и для Windows выполнять одну команду, для Linux другую. Различаются вызовы CLI в Windows и Linux, что логично, но никакая эта ни проблема. Если нужно автоматизировать кодом, то и автоматизируйте... В чём проблема то?! В описании Вы определили задачу отображать Word документ в PDF формате: берём Doc/DOCX, переформатируем в PDF, отображаем. Что конкретно здесь не подходит?!

Comment: @XelaNimed, я уже выше писал: "я в вопросе написал, что PowerShell и подобные [командные строки] не предлагать, так как эти варианты не подходят для решения задачи". Если это было бы допустимо, я бы не использовал бы это?

Comment: Но Вы не объяснили почему они не подходят. В чём причина? [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707962/3129992) приводится пример использования LibreOffice в .Net Core в не зависимости от платформы. Так-же Вам писал, что пару лет назад задавался похожим вопросом и пришёл к выводу, что или так, или покупать библиотеку за денюжку (для DOCX ситуация совершенно иная). Может быть за два года что-то изменилось, но в этом случае Вы бы нашли это решение.

Comment: @XelaNimed, мне поставили такие условия, я их перечислил в самом вопросе. Мне не подходит консоль, мне нужен API или плагин